# Check if entity from a room database is empty

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

How can I detect if a table has no entries using Room Persistence Library? I can't   find any information on how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 11):

Create a `SELECT count(*) FROM ...` query that returns an int or a `SELECT * FROM ...` query that returns an array and check the size of the array.

Comment: is there any way we could check this more efficiently?

Comment: More efficiently than what? It’s very hard to give a response to something as vague as "more efficiently"

Answer (score 2):

simply you can make a query and check if the result is empty.
Like this

this code in Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1")
LiveData<TaskEntry> loadlastTask();
```

then in your ViewModel class, you can call this and check

```
  LiveData<TaskEntry> mDBTask;
    private AppDataBase mDB;


    mDBTask = mDB.taskDao().loadlastTask();
    if(mDBTask.getValue() == null ){
    //table is empty
   }else{
     // table is not empty
   }
```

Comment: LiveData is asynchronous. There is no guarantee that condition `mDBTask.getValue() == null ` will always be the correct logic because `loadlastTask()` may not complete exactly before the if statement executes.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but since i need this information to remove a piece of UI, i created a function in the viewmodel to call the query in the DAO, and i'm trying to use this function to establish if the UI element must be removed or not in the fragment itself. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Execute a query which return the count of the rows.

Comment: How about providing the query you mention as well?